$||\phi||_{L^1}$ bounded by $||\phi'||_{L^p}$?
Say that $1<p,q<\infty$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, and say $f\in L^p([0,1],m)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. For $x\in [0,1]$ define $\phi(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$.
(1) Does there exist any $x\in (0,1)$ such that the derivative $\phi'(x)$ exists?
(2) Prove that $||\phi||_{L^1}\leq (q+1)^{-1/q}||f||_{L^p}$.
Now, for part (1) it is enough to note that $f$ is also in $L^1$ as $1<p$, and so $\phi'(x)=f(x)$ exists for almost every $x\in (0,1)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue Integrals. However, I am not sure of how to tackle part (2): is there some relation between the norm of a function and the norm of its derivative?

Note that since $f\in L^1[0,1]$, the function $f(\cdot)$ is also absolutely absolutely integrable as a function of two variables over $[0,1]^2$ and we can apply Fubini's theorem and Holder inequality to obtain
$$
\|\phi\|_{1} = \int_0^1 \int_0^t|f(s)|~\mathrm{d}s~\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^1\int_s^1|f(s)|~\mathrm{d}t~\mathrm{d}s = \int_0^1 (1-s)|f(s)|~\mathrm{d}s \leq \|f\|_p\|1-s\|_q.
$$
We then have
$$
\|1-s\|_q^q = \int_0^1|1-s|^q~\mathrm{d}s = \int_0^1(1-s)^q~\mathrm{d}s = \frac{1}{q+1}\implies \|1-s\|_q = (1+q)^{-1/q}
$$
and we are done.
Note: Inequalities of the form $\|u\| \leq C \|u'\|$ in various $L^p$ spaces are known as Poincare inequalities. Generally speaking, some sort of Poincare inequality exists as long as the domain of integration is bounded in at least one direction and $u$ is sufficiently "close" to $0$. The exact definition of "close" varies depending on the context but typically it means that $u$ has roots either in the domain or on its boundary, or $u$ has zero mean. The first is true here as $\phi(0)=0$ always.

That's a neat application of Fubini----thanks!
